# Square Terminal API - How to perform the the first Checkout in production

Tags: square-connect, square

We are trying to get the Square Terminal API running on a live terminal (i.e. in production) for the first time, having gone as far as we can on the Square API Sandbox.

When we pair the Square Terminal to our software using a Device Code, and then try to create a Terminal Checkout using the API, we're not getting any response on the Terminal, even though the API indicates the Checkout is pending.

We've tried everything we can think of.
Does anyone have any idea what we might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
I had to upgrade the software on the Square Terminal.  It took 5 rounds of software updates to bring it up to date, but now it works exactly as expected.